# SQL Server physical data layout for tables without indexes

Tags: sql, clustered-index

I'm curious to see if anyone knows how is the data physically arranged in tables that don't have an index (not even a PK). In this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705504/what-happens-when-i-drop-a-clustered-primary-key-in-sql-2005) the OP claims it is taking a long time to drop a clustered PK. I know that the clustered index is the data itself, but what would be the new data arrangement that explains the long processing time?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It will be a [**HEAP**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa964133(SQL.90).aspx):

> A heap table, by definition, is a table that doesn't have any clustered indexes.
>
> Different pages of the heap-based table occupy different non-contiguous areas on a disk, and they are not linked together in any way.
>
> Each non-clustered index defined on the table will have a corresponding entry in a sysindexes table with an indid between 2 and 254, pointing to the first `IAM` (Index Allocation Map) page.
>
> `IAM` pages represent the linked list of all pages used by the database object (table or index) and used by `SQL Server` for allocating and deallocating storage space.
>
> It is important to remember that `IAM` pages are not used to search through data or index pages, but only to allocate and deallocate them.

Comment: Hmm the link above gives me a 404.