# TSQL Alter PRIMARY KEY Cluster Index MSSQL2008r2

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, indexing, primary-key, clustered-index

is it possible to ALTER a PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED Index on an existing table without losing the data?

If so, what is the ALTER command for this please?

EDIT
I want to add an additional column to the PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED Index

Thanks

Comment: what are you trying to alter?  The columns that make up the primary key?

Comment: I want to add an additional column to the PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED Index

Comment: No, it's not possible to directly change a constraint definition. `ALTER TABLE` only allows you to add or remove a constraint, not change its definition. Also, constraints are backed by indexes. If you look at [`ALTER INDEX`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188388.aspx) you'll see that there's no way to change the columns included in an index. But removing and adding a constraint shouldn't cause you to lose the actual data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is what I've done in the past to change a primary key on a table:

```
BEGIN TRANSACTION doStuff

DECLARE @isValid bit
SET     @isValid = 1

DECLARE @pkName varchar(50)
SET     @pkName = (
    SELECT TOP 1 name
    FROM sys.key_constraints
    WHERE type ='pk'
        AND OBJECT_NAME(parent_object_id) = N'TableName'
)

DECLARE @sql nvarchar(2000)
SET @sql = N'
ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
DROP CONSTRAINT ' + @pkName

EXEC (@sql)

IF (@@ERROR <> 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Error deleting primary key'
        SET @isValid = 0
    END

ALTER TABLE dbo.TableName
ADD PRIMARY KEY (primary key columns separated by comma)

IF (@@ERROR <> 0)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Error creating primary key'
        SET @isValid = 0
    END

IF (@isValid = 1)
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Commit'
        COMMIT TRANSACTION doStuff
    END
ELSE
    BEGIN
        PRINT 'Rollback'
        ROLLBACK TRANSACTION doStuff
    END
```

Note as pointed out in: [Best way to change clustered index (PK) in SQL 2005](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/705790/best-way-to-change-clustered-index-pk-in-sql-2005?rq=1) this will reorder the data in your table throughout the operation, so depending on the size of the table it could take a significant amount of time.

Comment: Thanks for this.  How would this affect the Non Clustered Indexes on the same table?  Would they REBUILD at the same time or something?

Comment: http://www.sqlskills.com/blogs/paul/indexes-from-every-angle-what-happens-to-non-clustered-indexes-when-the-table-structure-is-changed/  "any change to the cluster keys forces all the non-clustered indexes to be rebuilt after the new clustered index has been created."